# form.clean() is called when generated

Tags: django, forms, validation

I'm generating a standard form together with TemplateResponse.
My problem is that the form is being rendered already validated (shows validation errors)
when it shows.

I see in the logs only 1 request to the server.

What can cause it to pre-validations?

Edit: this is the server code

> ```
> form = password_reset_form(request=request)
> context = {
>     'form': form,
> }
> if extra_context is not None:
>     context.update(extra_context)
> return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
>                         current_app=current_app)
> ```

I"m using Django 1.6
Thanks

Comment: You have to provide the code and the validation errors. Please edit the question. Dont use the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

In the Get I need to pass None form in the TemplateResponse's context parameter.

Comment: How did you find it? What is your source? This answer is not helpful, if you dont provide any detailed explanation.